# Java: casting Collection.class to Class<Collection<T>>

Tags: java, generics, casting

If I have the following interface:

```
interface MyElementProcessor<T> {
    void doSomethingWith(T element);
    Class<T> getElementClass();
    /* more functions... */
}
```

Say that I want to implement this for a generic type like `Collection<T>`. How do I implement `getElementClass()`?  My best attempt so far is something like this:

```
class MyCollectionProcessor<T> implements MyElementProcessor<Collection<T>> {
    public void doSomethingWith(Collection<T> element) { /* ... */ }

    public Class<Collection<T>> getElementClass() {
        // Ugly, but the only way I have found to cast to Class<Collection<T>>:
        return (Class<Collection<T>>) (Object) Collection.class;
    }
}
```

I know that there is no way to specify a `Class<Collection<T>>` literal in Java, but why isn't it possible to cast `Collection.class` directly to `Class<Collection<T>>`? Is there a better way than casting via `Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why isn't it possible to cast Collection.class directly to
>   `Class<Collection<T>>`?

`Collection.class` has type `Class<Collection>`. Java will not compile this type cast because it can be proved that it cannot succeed. There is probably no type that is a subtype of both `Class<Collection>` and `Class<Collection<T>>`.

In Generics, `Foo<A>` is never a subtype of `Foo<B>` if A and B are different and they are types (not wildcards), regardless of the relationship between `A` and `B`. Therefore, the only subtypes of `Class<Collection>` are `SubclassOfClass<Collection>`. And similarly the only subtypes of `Class<Collection<T>>` are `SubclassOfClass<Collection<T>>`. Since these do not intersect, there is no way this cast can theoretically succeed.

> Is there a better way than casting via Object?

You could cast via `Class<?>`; but it is not much better:

```
return (Class<Collection<T>>) (Class<?>) Collection.class;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the class literal to the constructor:

```
 private final Class<Collection<T>> clazz;

 public MyCollectionProcessor(Class<Collection<T>> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
 }

  public Class<Collection<T>> getElementClass() {
    return clazz;
  }
```

No cast needed but an extra parameter...

Comment: +1: Passing the class token explicitly and using `Class.cast()` is the way to go in Java when you need to get rid of unchecked casts. (Albeit not all of them.)

Comment: But not easy to pass in a `List<String>.class` (which does not compile).

Comment: Yes, this doesn't really solve the problem. Now the caller has to supply `Class<Collection<SomeElement>>`, which cannot be specified as a class literal.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Java generics handling, a `Class<List<Integer>>` class cannot be obtained (without unchecked cast), but will be `Class<List>` or `Class<List<?>>`.
Therefore, if you're working with parameterized type in your `ElementProcessor`, i suggest that you change your method to be `Class<? super T> getElementClass()`
Two examples :

```
interface MyElementProcessor<T> {
    void doSomethingWith(T element);
    Class<? super T> getElementClass();
    /* more functions... */
}

SimpleElementProcessor implements MyElementProcessor<Integer> {
    public void doSomethingWith(Collection<Integer> element) { /* ... */ }

    public Class<Integer> getElementsClass() {
        return Integer.class;
    }
}

CollectionElementProcessor<E> implements MyElementProcessor<Collection<E>> {
    public void doSomethingWith(Collection<Collection<E>> element) { /* ... */ }

    // This works because Class<Collection<?>> is a valid substitute for Class<? super T>
    public Class<Collection<?>> getElementsClass() {
        return (Class<Collection<?>>) Collection.class; // Maybe the cast isn't needed
    }
}
```

---

As for obtaining the elements class, you can use reflection : If your type **derives** MyElementProcessor you can obtain it like this :

```
for(Type interface :  getClass().getGenericInterfaces()) {
    if(interface instanceof ParameterizedType && ((ParameterizedType) interface).getRawType == MyElementProcessor.class)
        Type myElementsType = ((ParameterizedType) interface).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

*This only works for **deriving** classes, that is, anonymous classes or declared types, it won't work if you use it this way because of type erasure( this example is dummy : it is only an example)* :

```
public <T> MyElementProcessor newInstance() {
    return new MyElementProcessor<T> {
        // overridden methods ...
    };
}
```

In such a case, you will either :

- Not obtain a ParameterizedType but rather directly the MyElementProcessor.class, whose type argument is a TypeVariable and does not provide you with it's actual type implementation
- Obtain a ParameterizedType whose raw type is MyElementProcessor and actual type argument be a TypeVariable